# How to sum value of a column based on equality from another column and create a new dataframe

Tags: r

this is my first question on stackoverflow. I hope to describe precisely enough my problem.
So I'm trying to sum the value of a column called 'Fraction' based on equality of another column called 'Seq'.
My dataframe looks like :

| Fraction | Seq |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0872 | CASSFAVQGGETQYF |
| 0.0105 | CASSFAVQGGETQYF |

The hopeful output matrix should looks like

| Fraction | Seq |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0977 | CASSFAVQGGETQYF |

I would like a new dataframe to be created from this operation.
I have tried to use ddply but nothing successful resulted from it.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `df %>% group_by(Seq) %>% summarize(Fraction = sum(Fraction))`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in base R using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Fraction ~ Seq, FUN = "sum", data = df)
```

Or in dplyr using `group_by` and `summmarise`

```
df %>% 
group_by(Seq) %>% 
summarize(Fraction = sum(Fraction))
```